# Modify class variable via pointer to reference

Tags: c++, function, class

I have this class declaration that should set `hour`, `minute` and `second` variables within my `Time` class:

```
class Time
{
public:
     int hour; //0-23
     int minute; //0-59
     int second; //0-59
};
```

Now, This next code should work for that class definition:

```
Time clock;
Time *clockPtr = &clock;

clock.hour=8;
clock.minute=12;
*clockPtr.second=0;
```

Will this work? I think that because the pointer is pointing to the value of the address `&clock` it should work. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: Be careful with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: @RedX ... with all warnings on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you'll need to take care about the [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of the `*` and `.` dereferenccing operators. Just change that line

```
 *clockPtr.second=0;
```

to

```
 (*clockPtr).second=0;
```

or as [@Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744306/class-verifycation/26744469?noredirect=1#comment42074515_26744469) pointed out

```
 clockPtr->second=0;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/JLJa78)

Comment: The precedence issue can be eliminated by using the `->` operator: `clockPtr->second = 0;`